# JMeter - Stop remote server

Tags: jmeter

I am running JMeter in distributed mode (1 master & 2 slaves).

In my master machine, I issue below command

```
jmeter -n -t script.jmx -r
```

It starts the test in both slave machines & works great. If i need to stop the test (in non-gui mode), If i press `ctrl+c`, It just stops the master. slaves keep executing the test. I also tried `shutdown.cmd`. master shows that 'shutdown received from 127.0.0.1` but did nothing.

**Question:**

What is the best way to stop test while it is running?

Comment: I don't think there is easy way provided by jmeter to handle such situation. Workaround would be to call stoptest.sh/cmd on each server from server remotely using ssh. I am not sure if this a valid requirement but you sure can log a bug/limitation on bugzilla Jmeter list. Post the reply here for everyone. Thanks.

Comment: @NachiketKate, thanks. I think it should be valid as the GUI mode gives an option for 'Remote Stop All' to stop the test abruptly. There is no option in non gui mode.

Comment: Yes. Some mechanism/switch/option should be present in non-gui mode as well.

Answer (score 4):

Running shutdown.sh or stoptest.sh works well for me.

I run it on the master, the slaves receives the shutdown/stopsignal and starts to close down.

When running through jenkins, I issue the shutdown/stop command on the jenkins slave running the test.

Comment: Are there any things that have to do to make these scripts work?

Comment: Unless you have changed any config, they should work as is afaik. I have not altered them in any way. There may be a config option which port jmeter should listen on for shutdown signal.

Answer (score 1):

to stop the distributed test, you need to run the following command on the wizard: `./shutdown.sh`
do not forget to go to the jmeter / bin folder first. after running this command, the master will send all subordinates a command to stop the test